# GWT Editors for readonly and edit mode

Tags: gwt, requestfactory, gwt-editors

GWT's Editor framework is really handy and it can not only be used for editing **POJOs** but also for read-only display.

However I am not entirely sure what the best practice is for doing **inline edits**.

Let's assume I have a `PersonProxy` and I have one `Presenter-View` pair for displaying and editing the `PersonProxy`. This Presenter-View should by default display the `PersonProxy` in read-only mode and if the user presses on a **edit** button it should allow the user to edit the `PersonProxy` object.

The solution I came up with was to create two Editors (`PersonEditEditor` and `PersonDisplayEditor`) that both added via `UiBinder` to the `View`. The `PersonEditEditor` contains 
`ValueBoxEditorDecorator`s and the `PersonDisplayEditor` contains normal `Labels`.
Initially I display the `PersonDisplayEditor` and hide `PersonEditEditor`.

In the `View` I create two `RequestFactoryEditorDriver` for each Editor and make it accessable from the `Presenter` via the `View` interface. I also define a `setState()`   method in the `View` interface.

When the `Presenter` is displayed for the first time I call `PersonDisplayDriver.display()` and `setState(DISPLAYING)`.

When the user clicks on the **Edit** button I call `PersonEditDriver.edit()` and `setState(EDITING)` from my `Presenter`.
`setState(EDITING)` will hide the `PersonDisplayEditor` and make the `PersonEditEditor` visible.

I am not sure if this is the best approach. If not what's the recommended approach for doing inline edits? What's the best way to do unit-testing on the Editors?

Comment: If I am not understanding question wrong then you want to Edit/View feature for PersonProxy object. Why are you creating two Presenter-View for one object? If suppose GUI has same look for edit/view except widget visibility then you can achieve through make method which will set controls property like control.setEnabled(false); for view only (Displaying).

Comment: I have two separate Editor's for Edit/View. One is using Labels and the other Textboxes. 
I want to avoid having two Presenter-View pairs because the code is mostly redundant or trival (for displaying it's all about calling display() on the read only driver and for edit it's calling edit()).  The Presenter-View par is more like a Workflow thing.

Comment: @Ümit I take the exact same approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford developing 2 distinct views, then go with it, it gives you the most flexibility.

What we did in our app, where we couldn't afford the cost of developing and maintaining two views, was to bake the two states down into our editors, e.g. a custom component that can be either a label or a text box (in most cases, we simply set the text box to read-only and applied some styling to hide the box borders).
To detect which mode we're in, because we use `RequestFactoryEditorDriver` (like you do), we have our editors implement `HasRequestContext`: receiving a `null` value here means the driver's `display()` method was used, so we're in read-only mode. An alternative would be to use an `EditorVisitor` along with some `HasReadOnly` interface (which BTW is exactly what `RequestFactoryEditorDriver` does to pass the `RequestContext` down to `HasRequestContext` editors).

Comment: How do you handle pages where you have a mix of readonly and editable fields? ie. how do you do an edit() for some parts and a display() for other? Thanks!

Comment: We have 2 drivers, we `edit()` with one and `display()` with the other. Obviously, the screen must be split into 2 editors, each controlled by a driver.

Comment: OK thanks. Not sure this approach will work for me. I have a hierachy of Editors and depending on the data some sub-editors should be read-only. I wouldn't know which until I've done the edit/display and checked the data in setValue()

Comment: Would it be possible to have a `ListEditor` and allow a user to edit any item in that list on demand? By swapping out the read-only editor for an editable one on the fly, for example?

Comment: I had luck passing an `EditorVisitor` to the driver and checking the `ctx.getAbsolutePath()` if it matches a field I want to enable. Then `ctx.getEditor()` returns the field and I was able to cast it and call `setReadOnly(boolean)`. No need for two drivers or two views.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,Presenter-View pair should be. But Here two ways to achieve this feature if you like to go with:

1) Integrate Edit/View code design in one **ui.xml** i.e.Edit code in **EDitHorizonatlPanel** and View code in **ViewHorizontalPanel**.The panel has different id. By using id, show/hide panel with display method. if `getView().setState() ==Displaying` then show **ViewHorizontalPanel** and if `getView().setState()==Editing` then show **EditHorizontalPanel**.

2) Instead of using labels, Use textboxes only. set Enable property is false when you need it in view mode otherwise true

You have created two Presenter/view but I think if Edit/View function has similar code so no need to rewrite similar code again and again for view purpose.

If a big project has so many Edit/View function and you will create such type of multiple View/Presenter than your project size become so huge unnecessary.

I think that whatever I have suggest that might be not good approach but a way should be find out which help to avoid code replication.